# Convert this array to an HTML List

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array
  0 => string '3,6' (length=3)
  3 => string '4,5' (length=3)
  4 => string '7,8' (length=3)
  8 => string '9' (length=1)
```

OR

```
array
  3 => 
    array
      4 => 
        array
          7 => null
          8 => 
            array
              9 => null
      5 => null
  6 => null
```

Every `key` is the id and `value` is the id for the childs of this parent.
ID of 0 means that (3 & 6) have no parent.
Now, i want to output an HTML list like:

> - 3
>
>   - 4
>
>     - 7
>     - 8
>
>       - 9
>   - 5
> - 6

Comment: Why are they strings instead of arrays?

Comment: well, we can convert them to array with an `explode`... I have this array in various forms, but I am unable to generate this list from it. e.g. I have added another such form in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tree)

Comment: @Eric It is similar, but not a duplicate. That question handles for child->parent relations, not parent->children relations.

Comment: @Stoic: Go with the second form, if there's no additional overhead in doing so.

Comment: @Eric.. Yeah. Infact, as I commented to Alin's solution, I was achieving at first form after passing the second form in a function. Your solution helps me discard that function. :)

Comment: Yea the second form is easily preferable.  If that's what you had to begin with, I dont know why you'd go in the other direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
  0 => '3,6',
  3 => '4,5',
  4 => '7,8',
  8 => '9',
);
function writeList($items){
    global $arr;
    echo '<ul>';

    $items = explode(',', $items);
    foreach($items as $item){
        echo '<li>'.$item;
        if(isset($arr[$item]))
            writeList($arr[$item]);
        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
writeList($arr[0]);
```

[Test it.](http://codepad.org/y30JDXWy)

or

```
$arr = array(
    3 => array(
        4 => array(
            7 => null,
            8 => array(
                9 => null
            ),
        ),
        5 => null,
    ),
    6 => null,
);
function writeList($items){
    if($items === null)
        return;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($items as $item => $children){
        echo '<li>'.$item;
        writeList($children);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
writeList($arr);
```

Comment: +1.  I was going to split this into tree-building and the html output, but i like how yours worked out here.  very concise

Comment: Thank you, Alin.. Your function works awesomely well.. Though, just accepting Eric's answer because it saves me an intermediate function, I am using :)

Comment: Well... I made the first function for the format you posted the first time. I added one for the second format as well, but being such a standard implementation its almost identical to Eric's.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this format:

```
$data = array(
    3 => array(
        4 => array(
            7 => null,
            8 => array(
                9 => null
            )
        ),
        5 => null
    ),
    6 => null
);
```

Do this:

```
function writeList($tree)
{
    if($tree === null) return;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($tree as $node=>$children)
        echo "<li>", $node, writeList($children), '</li>';
    echo "</ul>";
}

writeList($data);
```

Test it here: http://codepad.org/MNoW94YU

Comment: @Alin: oops. I spotted that just as I posted it!

Comment: Thank You.. That was the real function I was looking for.. Simple, sweet and really concise... :) Added some warning checks to suit it to my needs 100% :)

Comment: What warning checks are needed, may I ask?

Comment: @Stoic: Wait, you actually __chose__ to turn your heirarchical array into a nightmarish hell of strings-representing-array-indeces?

Comment: @Eric.. Oh Yes. I definitely did. Because, I just had no idea on how to traverse a tree (recursion is one of the very basic things, we need to know and I just fail at it)

Comment: @Eric.. Oh, at the time I copied the function you posted, it needed to be checked for `null` values (`foreach` loop) while recursing. I can see that you've added that check. :)