# what does comma in echo statement signify?

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to echo a string from a Recursive function:
`echo "<li>", $node, recurse($arr), "</li>";`
and
`echo "<li>" . $node . recurse($arr) . "</li>";`

```
function writeList($tree)
{
    if($tree == null) return;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($tree as $node=>$children) {
        echo "<li>", $node, writeList($children) , "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

`$tree` is a tree-like structure, as can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392277/convert-this-array-to-an-html-list) (form2)

And, I can notice that the output from the two is different.
Can someone tell me the difference in using `,` and `.` in general, and particularly, in this example?

**EDIT**: what if rather than echoing the strings, I want to store the string generated from this function in a variable. I am, particularly, interested in the output received from the first `echo` statement.

EDIT: 
I am feeding this array:

```
array
  3 => 
    array
      4 => 
        array
          7 => null
          8 => 
            array
              9 => null
      5 => null
  6 => null
```

The outputs I am getting is:
(from first echo statement)

```
<ul><li>3<ul><li>4<ul><li>7</li><li>8<ul><li>9</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>5</li></ul></li><li>6</li></ul>
```

(from second echo statement)

```
<ul><ul><ul><li>7</li><ul><li>9</li></ul><li>8</li></ul><li>4</li><li>5</li></ul><li>3</li><li>6</li></ul>
```

Comment: How can they differ? Everything would be treated as a string before being echoed out...

Comment: I have provided the function I am using, the input array and the outpur for two cases. Just tell me, its not an error on my side and rather a conceptual issue. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** OK, I get it. The culprit is your `writeList()` function. There is a secondary `echo` inside that function.

When you do this:

```
echo "<li>", $node, writeList($arr), "</li>";
```

Each part is evaluated first and then printed out. It is equivalent to:

```
echo "<li>";
echo $node;
echo writeList($arr);
echo "</li>";
```

But when you do this:

```
echo "<li>" . $node . writeList($arr) . "</li>";
```

The entire string is constructed using the concatenation operators `.` first, then printed out. This means `writeList($arr)` is called first during the construction of the string, `then` the outer `echo` is called.

To avoid this problem, don't echo anything within your function calls. Build strings using the concatenation operator and then return them so that your outer `echo` can print them.

---

> what if rather than echoing the strings, I want to store the string generated from this function in a variable. I am, particularly, interested in the output received from the first echo statement.

Use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
echo "<li>", $node, writeList($arr), "</li>";
$out = ob_get_clean();
```

But for that particular statement, why not just concatenate instead?

```
$out = "<li>" . $node . writeList($arr) . "</li>";
```

Comment: I wanted to concatenate, as well. But, as I said, the two outputs are different here. :(

Comment: @Stoic: Paste the output in your question.

Comment: Have added the function, input and output for this.

Comment: So, the thing is that in the first evaluation occurs first and replaced one by one with function call, while in second string is constructed by calling recurse function, which rather than forming the string are actually echoing it at every level... right?

Answer (score 2):

`echo` is a language construct and can accept multiple arguments separated by a comma. The effect is identical to a concatenated string.

The output *shouldn't* be different - I can't think of an instance where it could be.

**Edit**: Ah, but it is. That is because your function `echo()`es stuff. In the first instance, `<li>` and `$node` get output; *then* the function's output comes.

I would have `WriteList` simply `return` values recursively.

Comment: I'm thinking of things like what kind of output is generated by that function call, but no dice. `echo` inside that function doesn't return anything that could be accidentally echoed by the outer echo.

Comment: Wait, I think I nailed it; see my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, I added the same thing just now :)