# Can I output this table of categories (id and parent_id) with only one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like:

[image]

What I want to do is output the main categories (those with null category_id) and under each one, list the categories that have that category_id as the parent.  That way, I create a little hierarchy output.

I could do this simply by doing a query that grabs all of the categories with null parent.  Then doing another query that finds the categories with that as its parent.  However, I am confident there's a way to do this in PHP/MySQL with only one query.

Any help, even conceptually, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there only one level of depth possible?

Comment: Yes, only one level of depth.  I don't foresee it going deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all categories at once from the database and build your hierarchical structure with a recursive function, see: [Convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE( c2.category_order, c1.category_order ) as top_order,
             c1.*
FROM categories c1
LEFT JOIN categories c2
ON c1.parent_category_id = c2.category_id
ORDER BY top_order, c1.category_order
```