# Tree Algorithm in PHP without Recursion

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a list of categories stored in mysql db. The categories can have child categories at any deep level user want.

**Database Table**

```
id  name                    parents
1   Apparel                                                                    
2   Appliances                                                                 
46  Apparel                 1                                                  
47  Child Apparel           1                                                  
48  Other Child Category    46
```

Now parents column tells me which category is a child of which parent. What best data structure algorithm I can use here without recursion in PHP?

Comment: Just wondering, is this homework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre). Includes recursive and non-recursive solutions

Comment: Mike the post is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/mysql/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html) explains how to store a tree based model, with the ability to look up children without recursive queries.

If the child nodes can be children of multiple parents, you should check out [this model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o)