# Specific algorithm to recurse through a tree structure in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, tree

In PHP, I have a structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
    (
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => 0
    )

    [1] = Array
    (
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => 1
    )

    [2] = Array
    (
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 1
    )

    [3] = Array
    (
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 2
    )
)
```

The `id` is a unique integer and the `parent` is a reference to another element's `id`. If `parent` is 0, then it has no parent. The tree structure looks like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 4
  -> 3
```

(I hope that is clear!). I have been trying to determine an algorithm that will produce a nested array or similar output that exposes the tree hierarchy so I can work with it; for instance one such output would be: `tree = ['1' => ['2' => ['4'], '3']]]`. The algorithm could support an array of any arbitrary depth; but I am limiting it on the proviso that a child cannot have more than one parent.

Apologies for the non-standard syntax, I hope it effectively communicates what I'm trying to achieve, which is a depth-first search, I think - however the implementations I've come across are too dry for my understand so I'd appreciate some help with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tre)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it infinitely easier if you use the key as the id.

```
$tree = array( 
    1 => array( 'parent' => 0 ), 
    2 => array( 'parent' => 1 ),
    3 => array( 'parent' => 1 ), 
    4 => array( 'parent' => 2 ) );
```

Now you can loop through all the elements simply appending them to their parent.

```
$newtree = array();
foreach($tree as $leaf) {
    if (!isset($newtree[$leaf['parent']])) $newtree[$leaf['parent']]=array();
    $newtree[$leaf['parent']][]=$leaf; }
print_r($newtree);
```

See what you get.

Comment: *The algorithm could support an array of any arbitrary depth...* Recursion is needed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/

Comment: No, recursion is NOT needed. His pre-existing list is 2 levels.. A list of nodes. Converting from that to a tree is easy.

Comment: @DanRedux His pre-existing list has 3 levels, `tree = ['1' => ['2' => ['4'], '3']]]`

Comment: That's not his pre-existing list. The thing he has is at the top. The result should be an array tree, but the input is just a list of items that can reference other items. It's not a real tree, just a list, so no recursion is required at all.