# PHP Recursion not stopping

Tags: php, recursion

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this recursion function.
I have an array with a tree of a website and a page I'm looking for can be infinitely deep.
The function goes through all possibilities but sometimes doesn't stop when it finds the right "page".

The array

```
$haystack = array(
    array("id" => 1,"parent" => 0,"route" => "home","children" => array()),
    array("id" => 2,"parent" => 0,"route" => "news","children" => array()),
    array("id" => 3,"parent" => 0,"route" => "photography","children" => array(
                array("id" => 6,"parent" => 3,"route" => "photography/portraits","children" => array()),
                array("id" => 7,"parent" => 3,"route" => "photography/countries","children" => array()),
                array("id" => 8,"parent" => 3,"route" => "photography/landscapes","children" => array(
                                array("id" => 9,"parent" => 8,"route" => "photography/landscapes/city","children" => array()),
                                array("id" => 10,"parent" => 8,"route" => "photography/landscapes/wilderness","children" => array())
                            )
                )
        )
    ),
    array("id" => 4,"parent" => 0,"route" => "about","children" => array()),
    array("id" => 5,"parent" => 0,"route" => "contact","children" => array()),
);
```

The recursion function

```
function recurse($needle = -1, $haystack = NULL){
    $_tmp = array();

    foreach($haystack as $key => $item)
    {
        echo $needle ." === ". $item["id"] . "<br/>";

        if((string)$item["id"] === (string)$needle){
            echo "Found: " . $needle . "<br/><br/>";
            $_tmp = $item;
            break;
            //return $item;   <-- this doesn't work either
        } else {
            $_tmp = recurse($needle, $item["children"]);
        }
    }
    return $_tmp;
}
```

Test cases:

```
$test = recurse(3);
print_r($test);

$test = recurse(7);
print_r($test);

$test = recurse(9);
print_r($test);
```

Last test outputs:

```
9 === 1
9 === 2
9 === 4
9 === 7
9 === 8
9 === 11
9 === 12
9 === 13
9 === 14
9 === 15
9 === 3
9 === 9
Found: 9  <-- should stop here, but continues

9 === 5
9 === 6
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Have you tried `return $item;` *without* the `break;`?

Comment: The question title isn't supposed to be funny, but I keep reading it over and over and laughing.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10777501/1420642  It's for nested comments, but it's almost the same

Comment: A foreach on null will throw an error and kill te script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified recurse function that fixes the problem you have:

```
 function recurse($needle = -1, $haystack = NULL){
    static $_tmp = array();

    if (count($_tmp) == 0 && $haystack != NULL && count($haystack) > 0) {
       foreach($haystack as $key => $item) {
          if (count($_tmp) == 0) {
              echo $needle ." === ". $item["id"] . "<br/>\n";

              if((string)$item["id"] === (string)$needle){
                  echo "Found: " . $needle . "<br/>\n";
                  $_tmp = $item;
                  break;
              } elseif (!empty($item["children"])) {
                  echo "calling ". $item["id"]. ".children <br/>\n";
                  $_tmp = recurse($needle, $item["children"]);
              }
          }
       }
    }
    return $_tmp;
}
```

Basically it declares a static variable `$_tmp` that gets initialized only once and and then a check to process the loop only if `$_tmp` **is empty** makes sure to stop further processing once *needle* has been found.

[**`Online working demo of above code`**](http://ideone.com/WXtNB)

Comment: I'm getting the value back, but is there a way to stop all processes? Your test output shows it continues recursion after it has found the needle. If ever I have a huge array, 1000 items or so, there's no point for it to continue if I'm looking for something in, say, the first 10. Also, if I could stop the process at that point then I would have the value returned anyway.

Comment: You can make it more efficient by another check of static variable's size inside the loop as in my last edit. See demo here: g ideone.com/WXtNB

Comment: Thank you, anubhava! Working :)

Answer (score 3):

It returns but continues in other recursion frame.
For example, calls: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4.
Return from 4 but 3 (1 -> 2 -> 3) continues to execute loop.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I thought return was supposed to stop it. I tried "break 2" but I get an error. I wan't the function just to stop everything :P

Comment: It is not good practice, but you can pass some boolean variable initially set to false by reference and set it to true before break. Before start of loop check it's value and return if it is true.

Answer (score 1):

You could go down the array only if you don't find anything on the level you are, something like this:

```
function recurse($needle = -1, $haystack = NULL){
    $_tmp = array();

    foreach($haystack as $key => $item)
    {   
        echo $needle ." === ". $item["id"] . "<br/>";

        if((string)$item["id"] === (string)$needle){
            echo "Found: " . $needle . "<br/><br/>";
            $_tmp = $item;
            break;
            //return $item;   <-- this doesn't work either
        }   
    }   
    if (empty($_tmp))
        foreach($haystack as $key => $item)
        {   
            $_tmp = recurse($needle, $item["children"]);
        }   

    return $_tmp;
}
```