# breadth first search / depth first search or Directed graph?

Tags: python, graph-theory, nodes, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have been struggling with this for a while now. given a set of nodes:

```
nodes = { ('A','B'),
          ('B','C'),
          ('C','D'),
          ('C','E'),
          ('B','E'),
          ('C','F') }
```

what is the best way to achieve the following:

```
                          A
                          |
                          B
                 _________|_________
                 |                  |
                 C                  E
            _____|_____             |
            |    |     |            C
            D    E     F        ____|____
                                |        |
                                D        F
```

where I can see that:

```
the routes from A -> B:
A -> B
the routes from A -> C: 
A -> B -> C
A -> B -> E -> C
the routes from A -> D:
A -> B -> C -> D
A -> B -> E -> C -> D

etc...
```

My reason for doing this, is purely because I want to understand how to.

I know that bfs finds the quickest route, (I think I might be using something similar in the get children function)

but I do not know the best way to loop / recursively run over the graph. Should I use a dictionary and work with key/vals or a list. Or sets...

```
def make_graph(nodes):
    d = dict()
    for (x,y,*z) in nodes:
        if x not in d: d[x] = set()
        if y not in d: d[y] = set()
        d[x].add(y)
        d[y].add(x)
    return d
```

I am using *z here as the tuples will actually include a float, but at the moment I am trying to keep things simple.

```
def display_graph(nodes):
    for (key,val) in make_graph(nodes).items():
        print(key, val)

# A {'B'}
# C {'B', 'E', 'D', 'F'}
# B {'A', 'C', 'E'}
# E {'C', 'B'}
# D {'C'}
# F {'C'}
```

the getchildren function finds all possible end points for the node root:

```
def getchildren(noderoot,graph):
    previousnodes, nextnodes = set(), set()
    currentnode = noderoot
    while True:
        previousnodes.add(currentnode)
        nextnodes.update(graph[currentnode] - previousnodes)
        try:
            currentnode = nextnodes.pop()
        except KeyError: break
    return (noderoot, previousnodes - set(noderoot))
```

In this case A:

```
print(getchildren('A', make_graph(nodes)))

# ('A', {'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'F'})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/102441). Not the same language, but same problem

Comment: Why does `E` not appear under `C` on the left?

Comment: Two each of C, D, F? Are you sure you want a tree, and not a directed graph?

Comment: I want to find all possible routes for any given key. I am not searching for shortest path ... and I do not know my 'goal'. I don't know if I want a tree or a graph, most of this was written without any prior knowledge of how trees and graphs actually work

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure where you mean?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: I meant right...

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus, agreed.  Based on your definition of nodes, E should have no children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before coding with a program language, you need to abstract the problem properly.

First you need to think about the properties of your graph, such as cyclic/acyclic, directed/undirected, etc..

Then you need to choose a way to solve your problem accordingly. e.g. if it's a acyclic, undirected and connected graph, then you can represent the graph as a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) and use either BFS or DFS to traverse it.

Finally, after you think through all of these, you can put it into code much more easier. Like what you've already been doing, you can give each node a list storing all the neighbors and use the [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to traverse the tree.

Comment: I'n my head, I know how to do it, but when I try and code it... I get confused.

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus put what's in your mind into nature language --> put nature language into pseudo code --> put pseudo code into real code

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, Problem solved. The function I needed to write was the following.

```
def trace_graph(k, graph):
    """ takes a graph and returns a list of lists showing all possible routes from k """
    paths = [[k,v] for v in graph[k]]
    for path in paths:
        xs = path[:-1]
        x  = path[-1]
        for v in graph[x]:
            if v not in xs and path + [v] not in paths:
                paths.append(path + [v])
    paths.sort()
    return paths


for path in trace_graph('A', make_graph(nodes)):
    print(path)


['A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'F']
['A', 'B', 'E']
['A', 'B', 'E', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an ordinary tree structure makes sense for representing your data, given that it's sequential but not necessarily ordered/sorted. It would probably be more appropriate to make use of either tries (either prefix or radix trees) or (probably better) directed graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be making things more complicated than they need to be.  Think about the type of data you are representing as xvatar has said.

For a basic directed graph a dictionary makes sense.  Simply store parent: list of children.

```
nodes = [ ('A','B'),
          ('B','C'),
          ('C','D'),
          ('C','E'),
          ('B','E'),
          ('C','F') ]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for node in nodes:
    d[node[0]].append(node[1])
```

Finding all reachable children from any root node is simple:

```
def getchildren(root, graph, path=[]):
    path = path + [root]
    for child in graph[root]:
        if child not in path:  #accounts for cycles
            path=getchildren(child, graph, path)
    return path
```

When calling:

```
>>> print getchildren('A',d)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> print getchildren('C',d)
['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Comment: But surely I can do this at the moment, the getchildren function does exactly this It just used sets instead of lists. in your getchildren function, why does C not return A - as (A,B),(C,B)

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus I assumed directed... as in the question title...  You asked for the best way to recursively run over the graph and to store data and I recommended using a defaultdict for easy creation and a simple recursive algorithm that will handle cycles when traversing.  If you're already doing what you wanted, what are you really asking?