# get and set values of object inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this 
**[Object, Object, Object]**

the structure of every object like this

```
0: Object
   children: Array[0]
   node_id: 0
   parent_id: -2
   text: "(r , e , w)"
   value: 6

1: Object
   children: Array[0]
   node_id: 1
   parent_id: 0
   text: "(r)"
   value: 3

2: Object
   children: Array[0]
   node_id: 2
   parent_id: 0
   text: "(e , w)"
   value: 3
```

**first** I have for loop and I want to get parent_id every iteration

**second** I want to put last two objects into the children array inside first object
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about what you want to have?
Can you also tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: I want to build a tree structure 
I want to put the last two objects into the first object children array

Comment: Then have a look at this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.parent_id);
    arrayOfObjects[0].children.push(obj.text);
    arrayOfObjects[0].children.push(obj.value);
});
```