# How to set records to a tree store in ExJS

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

I created a tree structure in my backend code and using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript) and now I need to set these *records* to a tree store, without traversing the tree again.

How can I replace or set these records to my tree store? 
What I do is like below but it doesn't work `tree.getRootNode().childNodes = records;`

Here are my *records*:

[image]

Comment: I would try to serialise the data and "set" them into a store with [setData](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-setData)

Comment: tree.getRootNode().removeAll();tree.getRootNode().appendChild(records);