# JSON to Tree JS

Tags: javascript, json, tree

Can someone please help me change this json:

These are the rules:
    The nodes of JSON (A) is sorted in no particular order
    The nodes of JSON (A) is mutable
    The "subordinate" node must not exist when there is no attached child to it (see markcorderoi or richard)
    The status indicates employment status, 1=working, 2=ended. All working nodes attached to ended(2) nodes should use the adjacent (uplink) working(1) nodes (ie marcoderoi attached to nssi, removing rudy in the final tree)
    JSON (B) should not contain ended nodes

JSON A:

```
[
  {
    "manager_name": "nssi",
    "login_name": "nishanthi",
    "status": 2
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "mbarcelona",
      "login_name": "nssi",
      "status": 1
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "nishanthi",
      "login_name": "markcorderoi",
      "status": 1
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "mbarcelona",
      "login_name": "richard",
      "status": 1
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "letecia",
      "login_name": "kamran",
      "status": 1
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "letecia",
      "login_name": "rudy",
      "status": 2
  }, 
  {
      "manager_name": "rudy",
      "login_name": "sol",
      "status": 2
  }, 
  {
    "manager_name": "gloria",
    "login_name": "maria",
    "status": 1
  }, 
  {
    "manager_name": "markcorderoi",
    "login_name": "gloria",
    "status": 1
  }
]
```

to this?

JSON B:

```
[  
   {  
      "subordinate":[  
         {  
            "subordinate":[  
               {  
                  "subordinate":[  
                     {  
                        "subordinate":[  
                           {  
                              "name":"maria"
                           }
                        ],
                        "name":"gloria"
                     }
                  ],
                  "name":"markcorderoi"
               }
            ],
            "name":"nssi"
         },
         {  
            "name":"richard"
         }
      ],
      "name":"mbarcelona"
   },
   {  
      "subordinate":[  
         {  
            "name":"kamran"
         },
         {  
            "name":"sol"
         }
      ],
      "name":"letecia"
   }
]
```

I am having really a hard time doing some algorithms using only Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18017869/6647153!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that link but still I can't make it correct. Please help.

Comment: I tried so many approach, and then I was stucked with this

Comment: success : function( data ) {
    var node = {};
    var map = {};
    var roots = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {  
     if ( data[i].status !== 2 ) {
      map[ node.name ] = i; 
      node.name = data[ map[ node.name ] ].manager_name;
      if ( data[i].hasOwnProperty( 'login_name' ) ) {
       console.log( data[i].manager_name );
      }
     }
    }
    //console.log( roots ) ;
    console.log( data );
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because your data does not contain items with no parent, so all children are collected and all parent nodes. Only the parents are uses which have been no children for the result set.

In `ended`, all `status === 2` nodes are collected and later deleted, if the nodes works as parent.

```js
function getTree(data) {
    var o = {},
        children = {},
        parents = {},
        ended = [];

    data.forEach(function (a) {
        var temp = { name: a.login_name };

        children[a.login_name] = true;
        parents[a.manager_name] = true;
        if (a.status === 2) {
            ended.push(a);
        }
        if (o[a.login_name] && o[a.login_name].subordinate) {
            temp.subordinate = o[a.login_name].subordinate;
        }
        o[a.login_name] = temp;
        o[a.manager_name] = o[a.manager_name] || { name: a.manager_name };
        o[a.manager_name].subordinate = o[a.manager_name].subordinate || [];
        o[a.manager_name].subordinate.push(temp);
    });

    ended.forEach(function (a) {
        var index = -1;
        if (o[a.login_name].subordinate) {
            o[a.manager_name].subordinate.some(function (b, i) {
                if (b === o[a.login_name]) {
                    index = i;
                    return true;
                }
            });
            if (index !== -1) {
                o[a.manager_name].subordinate.splice(index, 1);
                o[a.manager_name].subordinate = o[a.manager_name].subordinate.concat(o[a.login_name].subordinate);
            }
        }
    });

    Object.keys(children).forEach(function (k) {
        delete parents[k];
    });

    return Object.keys(parents).map(function (k) {
        return o[k];
    });
}

var data = [{ manager_name: "nssi", login_name: "nishanthi", status: 2 }, { manager_name: "mbarcelona", login_name: "nssi", status: 1 }, { manager_name: "nishanthi", login_name: "markcorderoi", status: 1 }, { manager_name: "mbarcelona", login_name: "richard", status: 1 }, { manager_name: "letecia", login_name: "kamran", status: 1 }, { manager_name: "letecia", login_name: "rudy", status: 2 }, { manager_name: "rudy", login_name: "sol", status: 2 }, { manager_name: "gloria", login_name: "maria", status: 1 }, { manager_name: "markcorderoi", login_name: "gloria", status: 1 }];

console.log(getTree(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your help!