# Service is not being called in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to Angular 2 and need help in calling service.

Here is the Plnkr I made:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wss2Jy41pYyjQUOk47es?p=preview

`Put code here`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Plunker is nice but the question should contain the essential parts directly. It also should contain what the actual and expected behavior is. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The plunker is not even running and doesn't allow to reproduce the issue. You can just use the `New` button in the editor to get a fully working minimal Angular2 application to start with.

Comment: hi, i just want to display the service data on my html page, services is being hit but not able to display the data

Comment: try this https://plnkr.co/edit/wss2Jy41pYyjQUOk47es

Comment: This Plunker is pretty much the same. Try this site https://angular.io/ for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have the `HttpModule` imported and included in your ngModule.

Second, you cannot display your `profile` just like:

```
{{profile}}
```

since your profile has properties like `username` etc.

Otherwise your code looks pretty good. Since your json looks like this:

```
{
  "profile":
    {
      "username":"eric",
      "bio":"Cofounder of Thinkster.io, kinda looks like Peeta from the Hunger Games",
      "image":"http://i.imgur.com/S66L2XZ.jpg",
      "following":false
    }
}
```

I would map the incoming data like so:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json().profile);
```

so you get a neat object to work with:

```
{
  "username": "eric",
  "bio": "Cofounder of Thinkster.io, kinda looks like Peeta from the Hunger Games",
  "image": "http://i.imgur.com/S66L2XZ.jpg",
  "following": false
}
```

Then you can display your profile with your properties, e.g like: `{{profile.username}}`

Here's a [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vrxCyAK3SE1FmcR9SEaN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @AJT, worked like a charm. you saved my lot of time. :)   
Thanks Alot.

is there any way to show jason data in a tree format ?

my data is like this: 

{"API_MODULE":"approvals","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"","API_RELATED_MODULE":"","WM_CONCAT":"RETRIEVE"},{"API_MODULE":"users","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"alternateapproverfor","API_RELATED_MODULE":"users","WM_CONCAT(API_CRUD)":"RETRIEVE"},{"API_MODULE":"users","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"alternateapprovers","API_RELATED_MODULE":"users","WM_CONCAT(API_CRUD)":"RETRIEVE"}

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :) Since this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Thanks @AJT, worked like a charm. you saved my lot of time. :)   
Thanks Alot.

is there any way to show jason data in a tree format ?

my data is like this: 

{"API_MODULE":"approvals","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"","API_RELATED_MODULE":"","WM_CONCAT":"RETRIEVE"},{"API_MODULE":"users","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"alternateapproverfor","API_RELATED_MODULE":"users","WM_CONCAT(API_CRUD)":"RETRIEVE"},{"API_MODULE":"users","API_RESOURCE_NAME":"alternateapprovers","API_RELATED_MODULE":"users","WM_CONCAT(API_CRUD)":"RETRIEVE"}

Comment: What data is this, and how is it related to this issue? :) just check how to create a tree structure in JavaScript and that should help you. You can check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript

Comment: HI AJT, i updated my plnkr still not getting the value, can you please help ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/wss2Jy41pYyjQUOk47es

Comment: Please recreate the issue in a working plunker. I can't debug it as it is. Plunker has template for Angular 2. And I did provide a working plunker, just compare the code there with your own ;)

Comment: Here's how you can create a Angular 2 plunker: http://imgur.com/a/5ASFa

Comment: Hi , i added new plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/XuVJXK1Jjlo3zjgM2awq

its just stuck on loading i cant see the username on other page. !!!

Comment: The reason why it wasn't loading was that you had no ngModule in your plunker,and the component paths were wrong. Your index file had some strange code. Check your index file. Of course the plunker index file is completely different from your actual app. So if your app isn't loading, you need to check your index file.7

Comment: i think i need some classes from you ;)