# Building hierarchy tree using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, tree-structure

I have a list of objects with a `C_PARENT` field.This parent field references another object in the list. I would like to create a tree hierarchy from this list based on this field.

Here is my data.

```
[{
    "C_ID" : 1.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Sparklers",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 2.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Twinklers",
    "C_PARENT" : 0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 3.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Candles",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 4.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Chakkars",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 5.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Colour Chakkars",
    "C_PARENT" : 4.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 6.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Chakkars",
    "C_PARENT" : 4.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 7.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Fountains",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 8.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Whistling Fountains",
    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 9.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Fountains",
    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 10.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Colour Fountains",
    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
},

{
    "C_ID" : 11.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Rockets",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
}]
```

I need convert into tree structure.

```
[
  {
    'C_ID': 1,
    'C_TITLE': 'Sparklers',
    'C_PARENT': 0,
    'C_STATUS':'Active'
  },
  {
    "C_ID" : 2.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Twinklers",
    "C_PARENT" : 0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
  },
  {
    "C_ID" : 3.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Candles",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
  }
  {
    '"C_ID" : 4.0,
    "C_TITLE" : "Chakkars",
    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,
    "C_STATUS" : "Active"
    children:  [
      {
        "C_ID" : 5.0,
        "C_TITLE" : "Colour Chakkars",
        "C_PARENT" : 4.0,
        "C_STATUS" : "Active"
      },
      {
        "C_ID" : 6.0,
        "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Chakkars",
        "C_PARENT" : 4.0,
        "C_STATUS" : "Active"
      }
    ]
]
```

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: is your data is an array of objects?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Ya my data is array of objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @ Tadeáš Peták .I tried but not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normaly used to create a new string with propertly info

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var data = JSON.parse('[{"C_ID" : 1.0,"C_TITLE" : "Sparklers","C_PARENT" : 0.0, "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 2.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Twinklers",    "C_PARENT" : 0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{   "C_ID" : 3.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Candles",    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 4.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Chakkars",    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 5.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Colour Chakkars",    "C_PARENT" : 4.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 6.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Chakkars",    "C_PARENT" : 4.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 7.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Fountains",    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 8.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Whistling Fountains",    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 9.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Fountains",    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 10.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Fancy Colour Fountains",    "C_PARENT" : 7.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"},{    "C_ID" : 11.0,    "C_TITLE" : "Rockets",    "C_PARENT" : 0.0,    "C_STATUS" : "Active"}]');

var result = '[';

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].C_PARENT == 0 || data[i].C_PARENT == "0") {
    if (i != 0)
      result += ']},';
    result += '{"C_ID" : ' + data[i].C_ID + ', "C_TITLE" : "' + data[i].C_TITLE + '", "C_PARENT" : ' + data[i].C_PARENT + ', "C_STATUS" : "' + data[i].C_STATUS + '", "children" : [';
  } else {
    result += '{"C_ID" : ' + data[i].C_ID + ', "C_TITLE" : "' + data[i].C_TITLE + '", "C_PARENT" : ' + data[i].C_PARENT + ', "C_STATUS" : "' + data[i].C_STATUS + '"},';
  }
}
result += ']}]';
result = result.replaceAll("},]", "}]");
var a = JSON.parse(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result + "<br/><br/><br/>" + a;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9h9a9ep/

Comment: Thanks for a reply.Actually, i am using typescript. I just used this var data = JSON.parse(menu list); I am getting this error  Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: rembember that you can debug it on the Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome by pressing 'F12' and going to the third tab you can put breakpoints to your js file press 'F5' to reload and see what is causing this Error, probably is for a bad formatted string or something bad builded

Comment: Now I fixed this issue using this line var data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c.json()));I am using typescript.i am getting another error  Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'String'.How can i fix this issue?

Comment: just add `String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
  return this.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};` is an improve of String class

Comment: Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'String'.

Comment: How to use typescript?

Comment: add it on the top of file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148385/discussion-between-anisundar-and-arngue).