# Building tree array of objects from flat array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to build a tree array from flat array:

Here is the flat array:

```
nodes = [
    {id: 1, pid: 0, name: "kpittu"},
    {id: 2, pid: 0, name: "news"},
    {id: 3, pid: 0, name: "menu"},
    {id: 4, pid: 3, name: "node"},
    {id: 5, pid: 4, name: "subnode"},
    {id: 6, pid: 1, name: "cace"}
];
```

> NB: id = node id; pid = parent node id.

I want to transform it into this array:

```
nodes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'kpittu',
    childs: [{
        id: 6,
        name: 'cace'
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'news'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'menu',
    childs: [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'node',
        childs: [{
            id: 5,
            name: 'subnode'
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I tried to use a recursive function to achieve the expected result, but I'm looking for a better approach. Thanks for your response.

Comment: please add your function as well.

Comment: Recommendation, if you don't figure out this yourself, you won't be able to learn or practice your recursive knowledge, instead fellow who answer this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a hash table and take `id` and `pid` in every loop as connected nodes.

This proposal works with unsorted data as well.

```js
var nodes = [{ id: 6, pid: 1, name: "cace" }, { id: 1, pid: 0, name: "kpittu" }, { id: 2, pid: 0, name: "news" }, { id: 3, pid: 0, name: "menu" }, { id: 4, pid: 3, name: "node" }, { id: 5, pid: 4, name: "subnode" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
                a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            }
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.pid === root) {
                r.push(a);
            } else {
                o[a.pid] = o[a.pid] || {};
                o[a.pid].children = o[a.pid].children || [];
                o[a.pid].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(nodes, 0);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you update to handle a slight variant? In this case there is no parent id. Rather it is assumed that if the depth is lower or the same as the previous list element its parent is its predecessor

Comment: @SumNeuron, please add a new question with your try.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292676/javascript-flat-list-to-tree-without-parent-id?noredirect=1#comment127720077_72292676

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Map object, introduced in ES6.

```
let nodes = [
  { id: 1, pid: 0, name: "kpittu" },
  { id: 2, pid: 0, name: "news" },
  { id: 3, pid: 0, name: "menu" },
  { id: 4, pid: 3, name: "node" },
  { id: 5, pid: 4, name: "subnode" },
  { id: 6, pid: 1, name: "cace" }
];

function toTree(arr) {
  let arrMap = new Map(arr.map(item => [item.id, item]));
  let tree = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr[i];

    if (item.pid) {
      let parentItem = arrMap.get(item.pid);

      if (parentItem) {
        let { children } = parentItem;

        if (children) {
          parentItem.children.push(item);
        } else {
          parentItem.children = [item];
        }
      }
    } else {
      tree.push(item);
    }
  }

  return tree;
}

let tree = toTree(nodes);

console.log(tree);
```

[image: Edit sparkling-feather-r6j3v]

Answer (score 1):

Iterate with Array#reduce and a helper object:

```js
var nodes = [
  {id: 1, pid: 0, name: "kpittu"},
  {id: 2, pid: 0, name: "news"},
  {id: 3, pid: 0, name: "menu"},
  {id: 4, pid: 3, name: "node"},
  {id: 5, pid: 4, name: "subnode"},
  {id: 6, pid: 1, name: "cace"}
];

const helper = nodes.reduce((h, o) => (h[o.id] = Object.assign({}, o), h), Object.create(null));

const tree = nodes.reduce((t, node) => {
  const current = helper[node.id];
  
  if(current.pid === 0) { // if it doesn't have a parent push to root
    t.push(current);
  } else {
    helper[node.pid].children || (helper[node.pid].children = []) // add the children array to the parent, if it doesn't exist
    helper[node.pid].children.push(current); // push the current item to the parent children array
  }
  
  return t;
}, []);

console.log(tree);
```