# JavaScript flat list to tree WITHOUT parent id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

This question builds on many similar ones like [Construct hierarchy tree from flat list with parent field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367711/construct-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-list-with-parent-field/22367819?noredirect=1#comment127716528_22367819)

However the twist is that there is no parent id.
e.g.

```js
[
{id: 1, depth: 1, ...},
{id: 2, depth: 2, ...},
{id: 3, depth: 3, ...},
{id: 4, depth: 2, ...},

{id: 5, depth: 1, ...},
{id: 6, depth: 2, ...},
{id: 7, depth: 2, ...},

{id: 8, depth: 1, ...},
{id: 9, depth: 2, ...},


{id: 10, depth: 3, ...},
{id: 11, depth: 3, ...},
]
```

What is a performant way to construct the following tree?
Note that the children always come after the parent i.e. one can see the tree from the `depth` value. For example, `id 2` is a child of `id 1` since its depth is 2 and `id 1` has a depth of 1. id `3` is a child of `id 2` since `id 3` has a depth of 3. `id 4` is a child of `id 1` **not** `id 3` because `id 4` has a depth of 2 (a step up) from `id 3`'s depth of 3

```
\\tree digram
1
  2
    3
  4
5
  6
  7
8
  9
    10
    11
```

Should have values like

```
[
{id:1, depth:1, children: [
  {id: 2, depth: 2, children: [...]},
  ...
]},
{id:5, depth:1, children: [...]},
{id:6, depth:1, children: [...]},
]
```

Comment: So the children always come after the parent?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, the children always come after the parent

Comment: Great, just wanted to verify

Comment: Do you want the tree as *output* (like you depicted) or as a data structure? If a data structure, which one did you have in mind?

Comment: @trincot see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array for this that has an index for each depth. At every moment, it will represent a path from the (virtual) root to the current node. When dealing with a node, its parent will sit at index `depth-1`, where it can be inserted in that parent's `children` property, and the node itself will be placed at index `depth`:

```js
function createForest(flatdata) {
    const path = [{ children: [] }];
    for (const obj of flatdata) {
        path[obj.depth - 1].children.push(path[obj.depth] = { ...obj, children: [] });
    }
    return path[0].children;
}

// demo
const flatdata = [{id: 1, depth: 1},{id: 2, depth: 2},{id: 3, depth: 3},{id: 4, depth: 2},{id: 5, depth: 1},{id: 6, depth: 2},{id: 7, depth: 2},{id: 8, depth: 1},{id: 9, depth: 2},{id: 10, depth: 3},{id: 11, depth: 3}];
const roots = createForest(flatdata);

console.log(roots);
```

#### Irregular depths

If the `depth` values do not correspond to the *actual* depth of the nodes, but leave gaps, then use a "dictionary" (a plain object) to record the mapping of the `depth` property values with which *real* depth they correspond with:

```js
function createForest(flatdata) {
    const path = [{ children: [] }];
    const depthMap = { 0: 0 };
    for (const obj of flatdata) {
        path[(depthMap[obj.depth] ??= path.length) - 1].children.push(
            path[depthMap[obj.depth]] = { ...obj, children: []}
        );
    }
    return path[0].children;
}

// demo
const flatdata = [{id: 1, depth: 10},{id: 2, depth: 20},{id: 3, depth: 30},{id: 4, depth: 20},{id: 5, depth: 10},{id: 6, depth: 20},{id: 7, depth: 20},{id: 8, depth: 10},{id: 9, depth: 20},{id: 10, depth: 30},{id: 11, depth: 30}];
const roots = createForest(flatdata);

console.log(roots);
```

If however, the only irregularity is that the depth does not always start at 1, but sometimes at 2, it will be more efficient to prefix the input data with a dummy depth-one node, use the first function, and then remove the dummy "root" (with depth 1) from the result.

Comment: How does pushing an assignment statement work?

Comment: The value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned. So first the expression is evaluated, which performs the assignment, and then the `push` happens, with that value.

Comment: Blowing my mind. Does this work if for some reason there is no depth 1?

Comment: No, it needs the depths to never skip an unused depth. So a sequence of 1, 2, 4 will lead to problems at some point. Same with skipping 1 and immediately starting with 2. There is no problem with jumping *back* with bigger jumps, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 ... is fine.

Comment: If you want a version where the *meaning* of the depth value is not used, but they could even be outrageous numbers like 12, 25, 28, 25... (where 12 really *means* a depth of 1, and 25 a depth of 2) let me know, and I'll add a version that supports such gaps.

Comment: It would be nice for it to use relative depth. The use case is a table of contents (TOC) and for some reason the package I am using sometimes starts with 2 instead of 1, but the format that children follow the parent is solid

Comment: Added a version that only relies on the relative comparison of depth-values, not their absolute value. They can have gaps, and 0 is reserved for the virtual root level. When `depth` values occur multiple times, they *must* all refer to the same level in the tree structure. So this sequence of depths is not allowed: 10, 15, 10, 12, 15. On the other hand, you can use *descending* values too: 1, 5, 3. Here 3 is considered deeper than 5.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the array and add each item to the tree as well as to a trail of breadcrumbs. Each next item either goes as a child to the last one or you backtrack through the breadcrumb trail to the correct depth where it needs to be inserted:

```js
const peek = arr =>
  arr[arr.length-1];

function toTree(arr) {
  const tree = [];
  const trail = [];
  
  for (const item of arr) {
    while ((peek(trail)?.depth ?? 0) >= item.depth) {
      trail.pop();
    }
    const current = peek(trail)?.children ?? tree;
    const treeNode = {...item, children: []};
    current.push(treeNode);
    trail.push(treeNode);
  }
  
  return tree;
}


const array = [
  {id: 1, depth: 1, },
  {id: 2, depth: 2, },
  {id: 3, depth: 3, },
  {id: 4, depth: 2, },

  {id: 5, depth: 1, },
  {id: 6, depth: 2, },
  {id: 7, depth: 2, },

  {id: 8, depth: 1, },
  {id: 9, depth: 2, },

  {id: 10, depth: 3  },
  {id: 11, depth: 3  },  
]

console.log(toTree(array));
```

This solution clones each item, in order to add the `.children` property. If no cloning is necessary, `item` can be directly mutated.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the last inserted objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, depth: 1 }, { id: 2, depth: 2 }, { id: 3, depth: 3 }, { id: 4, depth: 2 }, { id: 5, depth: 1 }, { id: 6, depth: 2 }, { id: 7, depth: 2 }, { id: 8, depth: 1 }, { id: 9, depth: 2 }, { id: 10, depth: 3 }, { id: 11, depth: 3 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { depth, ...o }) => {
        r[depth - 1].push({ ...o, children: r[depth] = [] });
        return r;
    }, [[]])[0];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```