# TypeScript flat Array to object tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I implement a UI for better Overview about our LDAP branchs.
For that I want to use Angular Materials Tree. It´s great and very intuitiv to click through all branches.
(https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview)

**What I have:**

Array of multiple LDAP paths as a String:

```
groups = [
     'cn=devops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de',
     'cn=devops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group2,c=de',        
     'cn=devops,ou=smallUnit2,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de',
     'cn=dev,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit2,o=group1,c=de',
     'cn=dev,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group2,c=de',
     'cn=ops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de'
]
```

**What I already did:**

I convertet this Strings to Array of standalone paths with dependencies.
example for groups[0]:

```
dependencies = [
   {id: 'c=de',          parent: NULL,            child: 'o=group1'},
   {id: 'o=group1',      parent: 'c=de',          child: 'ou=unit1'},
   {id: 'ou=unit1',      parent: 'o=group1',      child: 'ou=smallUnit1'},
   {id: 'ou=smallUnit1', parent: 'ou=unit1',      child: 'cn=devops'},
   {id: 'cn=devops',     parent: 'ou=smallUnit1', child: NULL}

]
```

**What I need:**

I need an Object in which all keys are paths of our LDAP:

```
{
   c=de: {
       o=group1: {
          ou=unit1: {
             ou=smallUnit1: {
                cn=devops: {},
                cn=ops: {}
             }
             ou=smallUnit2: {
                cn=devops: {}
             }
          },
          ou=unit2: {
             ou=smallUnit1: {
                cn=dev: {}
             }
          }
       },
       o=group2: {
          ou=unit1: {
             ou=smallUnit1: {
                cn=devops: {},
                cn=dev: {}
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

I already tried to use methods like that:
[Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)
But this algorithmus use push function to add the new branches to an arraykey. I need that the key is an object with more keys.

Comment: is the data sorted? id not, how do you distinuish between of ` ou=smallUnit1` from `ou=unit1` and `ou=unit2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use directly `groups`, because all information in the reversed order are present, and `dependencies` is not.

Basically you need to

- iterate `groups`
- split strings of `groups`
- take the values from the right side as key for an object and return for every step the inner object.

```js
var groups = ['cn=devops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de', 'cn=devops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group2,c=de', 'cn=devops,ou=smallUnit2,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de', 'cn=dev,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit2,o=group1,c=de', 'cn=dev,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group2,c=de', 'cn=ops,ou=smallUnit1,ou=unit1,o=group1,c=de'],
    tree = groups.reduce((object, string) => {
        string
            .split(',')
            .reduceRight((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object);
        return object;
    }, {});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this should do the trick (given your current example data) :

```js
const dependencies = [
   {id: 'c=de',          parent: null,            child: 'o=group1'},
   {id: 'o=group1',      parent: 'c=de',          child: 'ou=unit1'},
   {id: 'ou=unit1',      parent: 'o=group1',      child: 'ou=smallUnit1'},
   {id: 'ou=smallUnit1', parent: 'ou=unit1',      child: 'cn=devops'},
   {id: 'cn=devops',     parent: 'ou=smallUnit1', child: null}
];

let transformed = {};
let tracker = transformed;

dependencies.forEach(d => {
  tracker[d.id] = {};
  tracker = tracker[d.id];
});

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: hi thank you for your help. it looks like i can create only one branch. not a whole tree. or am i wrong?

Comment: No, it means you can create as much as you want, but the `dependencies` array you provided contains only one branch.