# Make object as child according to the Parent Id JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following data coming from the `API`:

```
[
  {
    "Code": "01002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001001003",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001004",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "02",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
  },
  {
    "Code": "01002001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01002",
  },
  {
    "Code": "02002",
    "ParentAccountId": "02",
  },
  {
    "Code": "02001",
    "ParentAccountId": "02",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001001001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "03",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
  },
  {
    "Code": "01002002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01002",
  },
  {
    "Code": "03001",
    "ParentAccountId": "03",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001001002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001003",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001005",
    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
  },
  {
    "Code": "01001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01",
  }
]
```

Look at the `ParentAccountId`.

As I need to pass it to the `treeview` component so, I need to convert it to something like this:

```
    [
  {
    "Code": "01",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "Code": "01001",
            "ParentAccountId": "01",
            "children": [
                  {
                    "Code": "01001001",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "Code": "01001001001",
                            "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
                            "children": [],
                          },
                        {
                            "Code": "01001001002",
                            "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
                            "children": [],
                          },
                          {
                            "Code": "01001001003",
                            "ParentAccountId": "01001001",
                            "children": [],
                          },
                    ],
                  },
                {
                    "Code": "01001002",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
                    "children": [],
                  },
                  {
                    "Code": "01001003",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
                    "children": [],
                  },
                  {
                    "Code": "01001004",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
                    "children": [],
                  },
                  {
                    "Code": "01001005",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01001",
                    "children": [],
                  }
            ],
          },
        {
            "Code": "01002",
            "ParentAccountId": "01",
            "children": [
                {
                    "Code": "01002001",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01002",
                    "children": [],
                  },
                {
                    "Code": "01002002",
                    "ParentAccountId": "01002",
                    "children": [],
                  },
            ],
          },
    ],
  },
  {
    "Code": "02",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
    "children": [
          {
            "Code": "02001",
            "ParentAccountId": "02",
            "children": [],
          },
        {
            "Code": "02002",
            "ParentAccountId": "02",
            "children": [],
          },
    ],
  },
  {
    "Code": "03",
    "ParentAccountId": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "Code": "03001",
            "ParentAccountId": "03",
            "children": [],
          },
    ],
  },
]
```

I want to make the the object as child of it's parent according the `code`. The scheme is if the `ParentAccountId` is null it's the top level parent, if the `ParentAccountId` is of length 2 then it's the 1st level child if the `ParentAccountId` is of length 5 then it's the 3rd level child then if `ParentAccountId` is of length 8 then it's 4th level child then `ParentAccountId` is of length 11 then it's 5th level child. As the 1st level child have 2 length of `ParentAccountId` then the subsequent children will have the `ParentAccountId` as `Code` of the parent plus. For better understading please see the second because my English is not that better.

I am confused about the logic. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create tree structure using `reduce` method to create recursive function where in each iteration you check if the parent id is equal to current element id.

```js
const data = [{"Id":"1","Code":"01","Title":"Account 01","ParentAccountId":null},{"Id":"2","Code":"02","Title":"Account 02","ParentAccountId":null},{"Id":"3","Code":"01001","Title":"Account 01001","ParentAccountId":"01"},{"Id":"4","Code":"01002","Title":"Account 01002","ParentAccountId":"01"},{"Id":"5","Code":"01002001","Title":"Account 01002001","ParentAccountId":"01002"}]

function toTree(data, pid = null) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.ParentAccountId == pid) {
      const obj = { ...e };
      const children = toTree(data, e.Code);
      if (children.length) obj.children = children;
      r.push(obj);
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = toTree(data)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey, @nenad your function it better and works for my multilevel data, can you explain about the performance that is it less performant than using a loop? If there is no performance issue than I will choose this solution otherwise I will go for a loop solution as I have much data.

Answer (score 1):

The logic involved is to first try and find the children of every object (Accomplished using `filter` to find all objects that have a `ParentAccountId` equal to each objects `Code`) and then filter the data to return only the root parents (objects with `ParentAccountId` equal to null).

Try the code below.

```js
var data = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Code": "01",
    "Title": "Account 01",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Code": "02",
    "Title": "Account 02",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "01001",
    "Title": "Account 01001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "01002",
    "Title": "Account 01002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5",
    "Code": "01002001",
    "Title": "Account 01002001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01002"
  }
]

rearrangeData = () => {

  var newData = []

  data.forEach((x) => {
    x['children'] = data.filter((y) => {
      return y.ParentAccountId === x.Code
    })
    var parent = data.find((y) => {
      return y.Code === x.ParentAccountId
    })
    if (parent && parent.children) {
      parent.children.push(x)
    } else if (parent && !parent.children) {
      parent['children'] = [x];
    } else {
      return x
    }
    newData.push(parent)
  })

  var parents = newData.filter((x) => {
    return x.ParentAccountId === null
  })

  console.log(parents);
}

rearrangeData()
```

Comment: Bro, It only works for the first two children, check I have updated the data in my code, your code doesn't work for that data.

Comment: I edited the code snippet. It works now. You can also access the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/dyyNrpM) as the snippet cuts off some of the logged data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting on a task at work so I figured I'd throw together an implementation of this for you. Not saying it's any better or worse than the solutions in the threads linked - just another implementation:

```js
const data = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Code": "01",
    "Title": "Account 01",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Code": "02",
    "Title": "Account 02",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "01001",
    "Title": "Account 01001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "01002",
    "Title": "Account 01002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5",
    "Code": "01002001",
    "Title": "Account 01002001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01002"
  }
]

function buildTree(obj) {
  // get all top level parents
  let parents = obj.filter((o) => !o.ParentAccountId);
  // loop over the parents and recursively call addChild to populate the tree
  parents.forEach((p) => {
    p.children = addChildren(p, obj);
  });

  return parents;
}

function addChildren(parent, obj) {
  // find all children for this parent
  let children = obj.filter((o) => o.ParentAccountId === parent.Code)
  if (children.length) {
    // loop over any children recursively calling this function to add nested children
    children.forEach((c) => {
      c.children = addChildren(c, obj);
    });
    return children;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

console.log(buildTree(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over every node and build a map of child-id to child.

Then, loop over the nodes again, but this time looking at the parent-ids and pushing the node to the parent if it is a child, or adding it to the root list. This response is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018037/1762224) with the addition of a custom key configuration.

I also added a method to remove the `children` field on any object that does not contain children i.e. leaf nodes.

```js
console.log(convertListToTree(getDataList(), {
  idKey : 'Code',
  parentIdKey : 'ParentAccountId',
  pruneEmptyChildren : true
}));

function convertListToTree(list, options) {
  options = Object.assign({
    idKey : 'id',
    parentIdKey : 'parentId',
    childrenKey : 'children',
    pruneEmptyChildren : false
  }, options || {});
  let map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    map[list[i][options.idKey]] = i;
    list[i][options.childrenKey] = []; // Attach a "child" reference holder
  }
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    node = list[i];
    if (node[options.parentIdKey] != null) {
      list[map[node[options.parentIdKey]]][options.childrenKey].push(node);
    } else {
      roots.push(node);
    }
  }
  if (options.pruneEmptyChildren) {
    pruneEmptyKeys(roots, options.childrenKey); // Remove empty
  }
  return roots;
}

function pruneEmptyKeys(tree, childKey) {
  let items = tree[childKey] || tree;
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item[childKey].length > 0) {
      pruneEmptyKeys(item[childKey], childKey);
    } else {
      delete item[childKey]; // Remove empty child list
    }
  });
}

function getDataList() {
  return [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Code": "01",
    "Title": "Account 01",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  }, {
    "Id": "2",
    "Code": "02",
    "Title": "Account 02",
    "ParentAccountId": null
  }, {
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "01001",
    "Title": "Account 01001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  }, {
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "01002",
    "Title": "Account 01002",
    "ParentAccountId": "01"
  }, {
    "Id": "5",
    "Code": "01002001",
    "Title": "Account 01002001",
    "ParentAccountId": "01002"
  }];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018037/1762224 -->
```