# Dynamic menu dropdown from database in angular

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I have come across an issue where I cannot figure out what would be  approach to make a dynamic drop down menu with sub dropdowns that comes from database. I made api that pulls product categories and subcategories from database and it looks like  this when I put it in model.

[db_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD4fe.jpg)

```
export class Category {
    id : any;
    parent_id : any;
    name : any;
    created : any;
    modified : any;
    status : any;
}
```

Example

```
  |id | parent_id  |   name      |        
  | 1 |      0     |   cars      |        
  | 2 |      1     |   ford      |          
  | 3 |      2     |   focus     |      
  | 4 |      0     |   maincat2  |   
  | 5 |      4     |   subcat    |   
  | 6 |      1     |   fiesta    |
```

records with id 0 are are main in list records that have parent_id other than 0 are submenus etc

Can anyone give me an insight in what my approach can be, or to point me to some example or answer here that I may have  overlooked because I have been researching for two days now, and I haven't found anything.

This is somehow close to what I am looking for to populate [example menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnBQO.jpg)

Comment: Check this post out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript to make a "tree array", once you make this tree array it will be easier to create your dropdown component

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for