# Create tree structure array from flatter array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, treeview

I have a flatter array like this

```js
const arr = 
  [ { org_level_code: 'BBI',   org_level_name: 'Bostwick',     org_level_parent_code: 'toplevel',      children: null } 
  , { org_level_code: 'CDI',   org_level_name: 'BBi US',       org_level_parent_code: 'BBI',           children: null } 
  , { org_level_code: '60',    org_level_name: '60 - Sidney1', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',       children: null } 
  , { org_level_code: 'BBC',   org_level_name: 'BBi Canada',   org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',       children: null } 
  , { org_level_code: 'BBI-2', org_level_name: 'BBi U.S. ',    org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',       children: null } 
  , { org_level_code: 'DEPT',  org_level_name: 'Dept',         org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI/BBI-2', children: null } 
  ]
```

From this array I need the array like this

```js
const data = 
  [ { org_level_code: 'BBI',              org_level_name: 'Bostwick',   org_level_parent_code: 'toplevel',     children: 
      [ { org_level_code: 'CDI',          org_level_name: 'BBi US',     org_level_parent_code: 'BBI',          children: 
          [ { org_level_code: 'BBC',      org_level_name: 'BBi Canada', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',       children: null } 
          , { org_level_code: '60',    org_level_name: '60 - Sidney1',  org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',       children: null } 
          , { org_level_code: 'BBI-2',    org_level_name: 'BBi U.S. ',  org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI',      children: 
              [ { org_level_code: 'DEPT', org_level_name: 'Dept',       org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI/BBI-2', children: null }
  ] } ] } ] } ]
```

As you can see in the example `"org_level_parent_code": "toplevel"` is the parent node and `"org_level_parent_code": "BBI"` is the second node of parent because first node has the relation with child one with `"org_level_code": "BBI"` and `"org_level_parent_code": "BBI/CDI"` indicates the *3rd level*. These slash separated string has the relation with their respective parent nodes.

The last string  *e.g.* `BBI-2` of the slash separated string has the relation with above node.

**Note-** Top level node can be multiple like `"org_level_parent_code": "toplevel"`.

I am really struggling hard to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @James no I have tried this but that one is quite different. I don't have the direct relation between with nodes like parentId and all.

Comment: You could look up the appropriate parent from the current node’s `org_level_parent_code` using a technique like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map`, to store node location, if next node found a parent node, push to that  parent node.

```js
const arr = [{ "org_level_code": "BBI", "org_level_name": "Bostwick", "org_level_parent_code": "toplevel", "children": null }, { "org_level_code": "BBI", "org_level_name": "BBi US", "org_level_parent_code": "BBI", "children": null }, { "org_level_code": "60", "org_level_name": "60 - Sidney1", "org_level_parent_code": "BBI/BBI", "children": null }, { "org_level_code": "BBC", "org_level_name": "BBi Canada", "org_level_parent_code": "BBI/BBI", "children": null }, { "org_level_code": "BBI-2", "org_level_name": "BBi U.S. ", "org_level_parent_code": "BBI/BBI", "children": null }, { "org_level_code": "DEPT", "org_level_name": "Dept", "org_level_parent_code": "BBI/BBI/BBI-2", "children": null }];

let map = new Map;
let result = arr.shift();
for (const item of arr) {
  item.children ??= []
  let parentId = item.org_level_parent_code;
  map.set(parentId + "/" + item.org_level_code, item);
  map.get(parentId)?.children.push(item);
}
result.children = [map.get("BBI/BBI")];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Nur thanks for your help.
But "org_level_parent_code" could be anything like YANKS/CINC or YANKS/CINC/YUI. So we will identify or map while iteration.

Comment: This is sensitive to order, if an item is encountered before its parent it will not be included in the result.

Answer (score -1):

We can add the nodes based on levels. Here is the solutions:-

```
const orgGreenTree = (array) => {
let levels = [{}];
array.forEach(function(a) {
  let level;
  if (a.org_level_parent_code === 'toplevel') {
    level = 0;
  }
  else {
    level = (a.org_level_parent_code.match(/\//g) || []).length + 1;
  }
  levels.length = level + 1;
  // console.log(level)
  levels[level].children = levels[level].children || [];
  levels[level].children.push(a);
  levels[level + 1] = a;
});
 return levels[0].children;
};
console.log(orgGreenTree(array));
```

Comment: This fails if a child element is encountered before its parent.

Comment: @pilchard yes you are right so data should be in sequence then it will work only.

Answer (score -1):

Here is concise, more generalized solution using `Array#reduce()`.

It accumulates into an Object whose properties are the paths to each item's `children` array. Top level items are accumulated into the `toplevel` child array which is the final result.

```js
const
  arr = [{ org_level_code: 'BBI', org_level_name: 'Bostwick', org_level_parent_code: 'toplevel', children: null }, { org_level_code: 'CDI', org_level_name: 'BBi US', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI', children: null }, { org_level_code: '60', org_level_name: '60 - Sidney1', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }, { org_level_code: 'BBC', org_level_name: 'BBi Canada', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }, { org_level_code: 'BBI-2', org_level_name: 'BBi U.S. ', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }, { org_level_code: 'DEPT', org_level_name: 'Dept', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI/BBI-2', children: null }],

  result = arr
    .reduce((acc, item) => {

      const parentCode = item.org_level_parent_code;
      const childrenPath = `${parentCode === 'toplevel' ? '' : parentCode + '/'}${item.org_level_code}`;

      acc[childrenPath] ??= [];
      (acc[parentCode] ??= []).push({ ...item, children: acc[childrenPath] })

      return acc;
    }, {})
    .toplevel

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This solution is not dependent on the order of the input array, and will correctly accumulate children even if the parent item hasn't been encountered yet.

```js
const
  arr = [
    { org_level_code: 'DEPT', org_level_name: 'Dept', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI/BBI-2', children: null }
    , { org_level_code: 'CDI', org_level_name: 'BBi US', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI', children: null }
    , { org_level_code: '60', org_level_name: '60 - Sidney1', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }
    , { org_level_code: 'BBI', org_level_name: 'Bostwick', org_level_parent_code: 'toplevel', children: null }
    , { org_level_code: 'BBC', org_level_name: 'BBi Canada', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }
    , { org_level_code: 'BBI-2', org_level_name: 'BBi U.S. ', org_level_parent_code: 'BBI/CDI', children: null }
  ],

  result = arr
    .reduce((acc, item) => {

      const parentCode = item.org_level_parent_code;
      const childrenPath = `${parentCode === 'toplevel' ? '' : parentCode + '/'}${item.org_level_code}`;

      acc[childrenPath] ??= [];
      (acc[parentCode] ??= []).push({ ...item, children: acc[childrenPath] })

      return acc;
    }, {})
    .toplevel

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```