# How to get desired category tree with top parent having predefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

Hi i want to get children tree from a category list.

here is my input data

```
[
  { "parent_id": -1, "name": "Toothpaste", "id": 99 },
   {
        "parent_id": -1,
        "name": "Cake",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 3,
        "name": "Chocolate  Cake",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 3,
        "name": "Walnut Cake",
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 4,
        "name": "Chocolate Cake mixin 1",
        "id": 6
    }
]
```

**my desired output** will look like below one

```
[ { "parent_id": -1, "name": "Toothpaste", "id": 99 },
   {
    "parent_id": -1,
    "name": "Cake",
    "id": 3,
    "children":[
        {
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Chocolate  Cake",
            "id": 4,
            "children":[     //<--- observe this one not there in my output 
                {
                    "parent_id": 4,
                    "name": "Chocolate Cake mixin 1",
                    "id": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Walnut Cake",
            "id": 5
        }
    ],
  }

]
```

The problem i'm facing is that i'm unable to push data into 2nd level i,e **chocolate cake** is having children but i'm unable to push that into chocolate cake children

**Note:** solution must work for any level of nesting

here is what i have tried

```js
function getChildrenTree(childList){
        let childMap = {};
        for(let i = 0; i < childList.length; i++){
           if(childList[i].parent_id === -1)
              childMap[childList[i].id] = {name:childList[i].name,children:[]};
          
        }
    
        for(let i = 0; i < childList.length; i++){
            if(childMap && childMap.hasOwnProperty(childList[i].parent_id) && childMap[childList[i].parent_id].hasOwnProperty('children')) childMap[childList[i].parent_id].children.push(childList[i]);
        }
         
       return Object.values(childMap);
    }

getChildrenTree([ { "parent_id": -1, "name": "Toothpaste", "id": 99 },{ "parent_id": -1, "name": "Cake", "id": 3 }, { "parent_id": 3, "name": "Chocolate  Cake", "id": 4 }, { "parent_id": 3, "name": "Walnut Cake", "id": 5 }, { "parent_id": 4, "name": "Chocolate Cake mixin 1", "id": 6 } ])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Not because in my case I can have multiple first level parent with `parent_id = -1`

Comment: In my code snippet `toothpaste` is one of the first level parent

Comment: @James in my case first level parent will always will be having `id=-1` otherwise it is not a parent.  in above comment i have made a mistake instead of `id` i put `parent_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach you can try.

```js
const flat = [
  { "parent_id": -1, "name": "Toothpaste", "id": 99 },
   {
        "parent_id": -1,
        "name": "Cake",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 3,
        "name": "Chocolate  Cake",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 3,
        "name": "Walnut Cake",
        "id": 5
    },
    {
        "parent_id": 4,
        "name": "Chocolate Cake mixin 1",
        "id": 6
    }
];

const makeTree = (arr, parent) => {
  const branch = arr.filter(node => node.parent_id === parent);
  branch.forEach(node => {
    const children = makeTree(arr, node.id);
    if (children.length) {
      node.children = children;
    }
  });
  return branch;
};

const tree = makeTree(flat, -1);

console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and and object for collecting the nodes and return a tree by taking all children from the root node.

```js
const
    buildTree = (data, root) => {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            ((t[o.parent_id] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children
    },
    data = [{ parent_id: -1, name: "Toothpaste", id: 99 }, { parent_id: -1, name: "Cake", id: 3 }, { parent_id: 3, name: "Chocolate  Cake", id: 4 }, { parent_id: 3, name: "Walnut Cake", id: 5 }, { parent_id: 4, name: "Chocolate Cake mixin 1", id: 6 }],
    tree = buildTree(data, -1);


console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: great  solution !! but understanding code is not our level i guess, its very high level.  could you please explain these 2 lines `Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, { ...o });
            ((t[o.parent_id] ??= {}).children ??= []).push(t[o.id]);`

Comment: it basically takes `id` as key as reference to the object `t` and the parent `parent_id` as well for paren. but for parent it created maybe unseen `id` object and adds the children inside. this is later the reference for using the root `parent_id` of `-1` to get the complete tree. for example build a tree of only one random node and have a look to `t`. basically it creates always two references, one for the parent relation and another for the children relation in a single loop.