# Build tree array from flat ordered array when only "depth" and NOT "parent ID" is known

Tags: javascript, tree

The answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript) and in other places I've searched only work if "parent_id" is known for each object in the array.

What if the only property for the objects is `depth`?

The depth essentially tells me if the item is a "root node" (`depth` of 1) or a "child node" (`depth` of 2 or more).

A child's parent is the object directly before it if the preceding object has a smaller `depth`. (The parent's depth should always be 1 more than its child.)

If an object and the preceding object has the same `depth`, then they are actually siblings on the same level

If the preceding object has a higher `depth`, then the current item is actually the sibling of the earliest preceding item that has the same `depth` (or you could also look at it as the child of the earliest preceding item that has a lower `depth`)

E.g.

```
// Please note "name" in the example below 
// is just for illustrative purposes.
// My actual array will have random names

const items = [
    {
        name: "1",
        depth: 1,
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        depth: 1,
    },
    {
        name: "2_1",
        depth: 2,
    },
    {
        name: "2_1_1",
        depth: 3,
    },
    {
        name: "2_1_2",
        depth: 3,
    },
    {
        name: "2_2",
        depth: 2,
    },
]
```

So I would want to convert that flat array into a tree like:

```
const newItems = [
    {
        name: "1",
        depth: 1,
        children: [],
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        depth: 1,
        children: [
            {
                name: "2_1",
                depth: 2,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "2_1_1",
                        depth: 3,
                        children: [],
                    },
                    {
                        name: "2_1_2",
                        depth: 3,
                        children: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "2_2",
                depth: 2,
                children: [],
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a helper array for the levels and assign the object to the latest array of the `depth`.

```js
const
    items = [{ name: "1", depth: 1 }, { name: "2", depth: 1 }, { name: "2_1", depth: 2 }, { name: "2_1_1", depth: 3 }, { name: "2_1_2", depth: 3 }, { name: "2_2", depth: 2 }],
    tree = [],
    levels = [tree];

items.forEach(o =>
    levels[o.depth - 1].push({ ...o, children: levels[o.depth] = [] })
);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```