# How can I sort Array of objects by parentId JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I sort this array?
I am trying to group an array of objects from a `parentId` that each element of the array brings, there can always be an indeterminate number of levels, the result I expect is the one I have in the output.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "parentID": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "645",
    "name": "ABC 2",
    "parentID": "123"
  },
  {
    "_id": "65",
    "name": "ABC 3",
    "parentID": ""
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "parentID": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "_id": "645",
        "name": "ABC 2",
        "parentID": "123"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "65",
    "name": "ABC 3",
    "parentID": ""
  }
]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Removed references to Typescript and React since this is a basic Javascript question

Comment: Can you look into this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript. Only the tree creation. For sorting you will still need some work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/Bobkorinek/3sgpqf0a/6/) should work even for nested children:

```js
const input = [{
        "_id": "123",
        "name": "ABC",
        "parentID": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": "645",
        "name": "ABC 2",
        "parentID": "123"
    },
    {
        "_id": "65",
        "name": "ABC 3",
        "parentID": "645"
    }
]

function map(data) {
    const childMap = data.reduce((map, child) => {
        return {
            ...map,
            [child._id]: {
                ...child
            }
        };
    }, {});

    const root = [];

    Object.values(childMap).forEach((child) => {
        if (child.parentID) {
            if (childMap[child.parentID]) {
                const parent = childMap[child.parentID];
                if (!parent.children) {
                    parent.children = [];
                }

                parent.children.push(child)
            }
        } else {
            root.push(child);
        }
    })

    return root;
}

console.log(map(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach with `reduce` and `filter`

```js
const input = [{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "parentID": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "645",
    "name": "ABC 2",
    "parentID": "123"
  },
  {
    "_id": "65",
    "name": "ABC 3",
    "parentID": ""
  }
]

function mapChildren(data) {
  //set the output with all results having no parent ids by default
  let output = data.filter(x => !x.parentId)

  //add children to existing results
  output = data.reduce((result, current) => {
    const {
      parentID
    } = current

    if (!parentID) {
      return result
    }

    const existingRecord = result.find(x => x._id === parentID)

    if (existingRecord) {
      if(!existingRecord.children) {
        existingRecord.children = []
      }
    
      existingRecord.children.push({...current})
    }

    return result

  }, output)

  return output
}

console.log(mapChildren(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like that is a job for database engines. You are not supposed to do this on Controller's side. The Model is supposed to send you data the way you want. Just ask the backend guy to make a route with the data sent like that, or just add some `if` statements to your data parsing method to do stuff differently based on whether an object has parentId or not.

But if you really want to do it on frontend side, you can do it like this:

```
const data = [
    {
        _id: '123',
        name: 'ABC',
        parentID: '',
    },
    {
        _id: '645',
        name: 'ABC 2',
        parentID: '123',
    },
    {
        _id: '65',
        name: 'ABC 3',
        parentID: '',
    },
];

const restructureData = (data) => {
    const children = data.filter((object) => object.parentID);
    const parents = data.filter((object) => !object.parentID);

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        let parentIndex = parents
            .map((object) => object._id)
            .indexOf(children[i].parentID);
        if (!parents[parentIndex].children) {
            parents[parentIndex].children = [];
        }
        parents[parentIndex].children.push(children[i]);
    }
    return parents;
};

console.log(restructureData(data));
```

This will not work for nested children though.