# Best way to convert an Array to a Tree TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tree

I have an array of nodes (`Node[]`) where node is described as following

```js
export interface Node {
  id:number;
  value:any;
  parent:number|null|undefined|false;
}
```

I want to convert it to a nested array of tree-nodes (`TreeNode[]`) where

```js
class TreeNode {
  private _id:Node['id'];
  private _value:Node['value'];
  private _parent:Node['parent'];

  private _children:TreeNode[] = [];

  /* some other attributes */

  constructor(node:Node, children:TreeNode[]){
    this._id = node.id;
    this._value = node.value;
    this._parent = node.parent;
    this.children = children; // special setter not a mistake
  }

  /* Some other suff here */
```

In my Tree root I have the following function to deal with conversion

```js
  // note before this all items in array having parent `null|undefined|false` are replaced with `-1` as all ids are positive
  parseTree(array:Node[], id:Node['parent']=-1):TreeNode[] {
    let tree:TreeNode[] = [];
    array.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item.parent !== id) 
        return;
      tree.push(new TreeNode(item, this.parseTree(array, item.id)));
    });
    return tree;
  };
```

this works but the problem is, the larger the array the longer it takes to execute. It's arounde N² complexity as it loops through all the items again and again. I tried removing the checked items this way

```js
  array.splice(index, 1);
  tree.push(new TreeNode(item, this.parseTree(array, item.id)));
```

but it crashes. How can I optimize this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard close enough, but not exactly as I have different DataTypes for Input/Output. but this gave me an hint, to apply the same logic with indexes instead of nodes references, Thanks