# How can I parse my input to have a folder structure like response

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the folowwing input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c",
        "name": "email",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
            "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2",
        "name": "purpose",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
            "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
            "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9",
        "name": "usage",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
            "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
            "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df",
        "name": "e164Number",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
            "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80",
        "name": "number",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
            "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73",
        "name": "testArray",
        "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
            "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
            "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
            "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
            "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73"
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
        "name": "companyInfo"
    },
    {
        "id": "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
        "name": "primaryContact"
    },
    {
        "id": "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
        "name": "contactInfo"
    },
    {
        "id": "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
        "name": "emails"
    },
    {
        "id": "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
        "name": "variation"
    },
    {
        "id": "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
        "name": "phoneNumbers"
    }
]
```

- We can assume that the last item of the any `idPathOfEntityToAttribute`
  array is the 'file' attribute
- Anything else above the last item is considered a 'folder'
- The ones that doesn't have `idPathOfEntityToAttribute` are references to the folders
- Need to allocate each item in the correct folder
- I need to reduce this to have a folder hierchy style check the expected output

I have tried multiple approaches like recursive/plain reduce functions but no luck, i tried the following:

```
const assignFolders = (
  dataMapNodes: DataMapSearchNode[],
  pathIds: string[],
  pathId: string,
  parentId?: string,
): DattaMapNodeInput | null => {
  if (pathIds.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const currentDataNode = dataMapNodes.find((node) => node.id === pathId);
  const lastDomainId = pathIds[pathIds.length - 1];

  if (currentDataNode) {
    const newPathId = pathIds.slice(1);

    // const shareSameLastDomain = dataMapNodes.filter((dataMap) => {
    //   const currentPathId = dataMap.subAttributes?.idPathOfEntityToAttribute;
    //   if (currentPathId && currentPathId[currentPathId.length - 1] === lastDomainId) {
    //     return dataMap;
    //   }
    //   return null;
    // });

    const children = assignFolders(
      dataMapNodes,
      newPathId,
      newPathId[0],
      `${parentId}-sub-0`,
    );

    return {
      ...currentDataNode,
      id: `${parentId}-sub-0`,
      type: currentDataNode.dataMapType,
      name: currentDataNode.name,
      parentId,
      children: (children && [children]) || null,
    };
  }

  return null;
};
```

this is the expected output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
    "name": "companyInfo",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
        "name": "primaryContact",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
            "name": "contactInfo",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
                "name": "phoneNumbers",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df",
                    "name": "e164Number",
                    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
                      "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80",
                    "name": "number",
                    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
                      "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73",
                    "name": "testArray",
                    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
                      "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
            "name": "emails",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
                "name": "variation",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "id": "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2",
                    "name": "purpose",
                    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                      "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
                      "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
                      "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9",
                    "name": "usage",
                    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                      "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
                      "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
                      "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c",
                "name": "email",
                "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
                  "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
                  "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
                  "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
                  "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
                  "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the example you have given. Also, could you split your main paragraph (that is one long sentence) into separate phrases?

Comment: In your edit please also define "current object" and it would be appreciated if you could shorten your example as much as possible while retaining the essential bits. trincot's request for the expected output is something you should provide whenever you give an example in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired from [Build tree array from flat array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)

This is a few steps process comments are in code.

1. For simplicity, we sort by longest path so that we can create correct path for our parents that has no path (they could be references). If order does matter, let me know.
2. For simplicity, we build a dictionary object to access items by their id.
3. Now indeed for each item we first make sure that each of its parents, has the correct parents as well (minus one)
4. Now we can attach every item to it's parent node children, or to the root of the tree.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c",
    "name": "email",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
      "b45b8121-ea80-4ba5-970f-a963eadc0c8c"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2",
    "name": "purpose",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
      "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
      "dc5b0d11-6e97-46f0-b9be-ecd4f9ab88d2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9",
    "name": "usage",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
      "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
      "78e48433-0811-40d0-9b1f-c03a567eeaf9"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df",
    "name": "e164Number",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
      "09956860-ae67-4458-b422-323c0adb82df"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80",
    "name": "number",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
      "e5249e27-58b5-4041-bc2d-e0cccf78cd80"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73",
    "name": "testArray",
    "idPathOfEntityToAttribute": [
      "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
      "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
      "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
      "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
      "a881cfca-2655-4270-a317-7a83d15c3b73"
    ]
  },

  {
    "id": "a12b7e26-6a50-422e-81a0-1c71598cdfb8",
    "name": "companyInfo"
  },
  {
    "id": "676723c9-2795-406a-a775-d3294c095d6e",
    "name": "primaryContact"
  },
  {
    "id": "c30421e8-2d32-4810-aae9-7d1a6739b41b",
    "name": "contactInfo"
  },
  {
    "id": "e4f41922-8657-49f0-9831-615bd7887f33",
    "name": "emails"
  },
  {
    "id": "5ed46c31-6349-4d38-8a6f-512dbfa3d28a",
    "name": "variation"
  },
  {
    "id": "ba03a1af-3a9a-466b-b5ec-8d744f620e66",
    "name": "phoneNumbers"
  }
]

function unflatten(arr) {
  var tree = []

  // sort by depth (leaves first)
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    var len_a = a.idPathOfEntityToAttribute ? a.idPathOfEntityToAttribute.length : 0
    var len_b = b.idPathOfEntityToAttribute ? b.idPathOfEntityToAttribute.length : 0
    return len_b - len_a
  })

  // group by id for easy access
  var grouped = arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    agg[item.id] = item
    item.children = []
    return agg;
  }, {})

  Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function(key) {
    var item = grouped[key];

    // make sure ancestors has correct idPathOfEntityToAttribute
    var path = [...item.idPathOfEntityToAttribute]
    var folder = path.pop()
    while (path.length) {
      folder = path.pop()
      grouped[folder].idPathOfEntityToAttribute = [...path, folder]
    }

    // attach to the tree or to the parent
    var len = item.idPathOfEntityToAttribute.length
    var parent_id = len > 1 ? item.idPathOfEntityToAttribute[len - 2] : null
    if (parent_id) {
      var parent = grouped[parent_id]
      if (!parent) {
        throw new Error("missing parent: " + parent_id + " - possible create it?")
      }
      parent.children.push(item);
    } else {
      tree.push(item)
    }
  })

  // optionally clean by removing idPathOfEntityToAttribute
  Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function(key) {
    var item = grouped[key];
    delete item.idPathOfEntityToAttribute
  })

  return tree;
}


var tree = unflatten(arr)

console.log(tree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```