# Find the parent of a javascript tree object array

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

Find the bellow parent child tree object I have created. I need to find the root parent of a given child id. For example child id - 242 root parent id is 238. There are similar questions have been asked and this is the one I found very similar to my question.

[Convert parent-child array to tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792794/convert-parent-child-array-to-tree/23939907)

I have change the original code a bit But not working for child element. The issue is here. when it comes the recursive function with `rootNode.children` for loop will not execute since it does not loop through children. But if I change the for loop  `for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.length; i++)`  to `for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.children.length; i++)` then it break on first loop since does not have children. I'm sure with small code change this can make work.

```js
var getParent = function (rootNode, rootId) {

if (rootNode.id === rootId)
    return rootNode;

//for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.children.length; i++) -- original code line not working first time 
for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.length; i++) {
    var child = rootNode[i];
    if (child.id === rootId)
        return child;

    if (typeof child.children !== 'undefined')
        var childResult = getParent(child, rootId);

    if (childResult != null) return childResult;
}
return null;
};

var mytree = [
{
    "id": 245,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 246,
            "parent": "245",
            "title": "sub task 1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 238,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project2",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 240,
            "parent": "238",
            "title": "sub task 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 242,
            "parent": "238",
            "title": "sub task 3",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id": 241,
                    "parent": "242",
                    "title": "sub task 3.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 173,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project3"
}
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(getParent(mytree, 238)['title']));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getParent(mytree, 241)));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to iterate the given root node, because this is an array, not an object.

```js
function getParent(root, id) {
    var node;

    root.some(function (n) {
        if (n.id === id) {
            return node = n;
        }
        if (n.children) {
            return node = getParent(n.children, id);
        }
    });
    return node || null;
}


var mytree = [{ id: 245, parent: "0", title: "project1", children: [{ id: 246, parent: "245", title: "sub task 1" }] }, { id: 238, parent: "0", title: "project2", children: [{ id: 240, parent: "238", title: "sub task 2" }, { id: 242, parent: "238", title: "sub task 3", children: [{ id: 241, parent: "242", title: "sub task 3.1" }] }] }, { id: 173, parent: "0", title: "project3" }];

console.log(getParent(mytree, 238));
console.log(getParent(mytree, 241));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

More a classical attempt

```js
function getParent(root, id) {
    var i, node;
    for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
        node = root[i];
        if (node.id === id || node.children && (node = getParent(node.children, id))) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var mytree = [{ id: 245, parent: "0", title: "project1", children: [{ id: 246, parent: "245", title: "sub task 1" }] }, { id: 238, parent: "0", title: "project2", children: [{ id: 240, parent: "238", title: "sub task 2" }, { id: 242, parent: "238", title: "sub task 3", children: [{ id: 241, parent: "242", title: "sub task 3.1" }] }] }, { id: 173, parent: "0", title: "project3" }];

console.log(getParent(mytree, 238));
console.log(getParent(mytree, 241));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but do you know the way to get from root of array?

Comment: do you meen you have an object as root? than you could wrap it in an array for calling, like `getParent([rootObject], someId)`.

Comment: ! I mean like your example, when I call `getParent(mytree, 238)` it will return an array from root *id: 245*

Comment: @huykon225, i don't understand the question. please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think my js tools can help you
https://github.com/wm123450405/linqjs

```js
var mytree = [
{
    "id": 245,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 246,
            "parent": "245",
            "title": "sub task 1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 238,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project2",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 240,
            "parent": "238",
            "title": "sub task 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 242,
            "parent": "238",
            "title": "sub task 3",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id": 241,
                    "parent": "242",
                    "title": "sub task 3.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 173,
    "parent": "0",
    "title": "project3"
}
];
//node.asEnumerable get a Tree object
//isAncestorOf to predicate the root node is or not the ancestor node of parameter
console.log(mytree.find(node => node.asEnumerable(node => node.children, node => node.id).isAncestorOf(241)));
console.log(mytree.find(node => node.asEnumerable(node => node.children, node => node.id).isAncestorOf(242)).title);
```

```html
<script src="https://wm123450405.github.io/linqjs/libs/linq-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written