# How to get subtree table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this :

```
id    title      parent_id
1       A           0
2       B           0
3       C           1
4       F           3
5       O           3
6       D           2
7       J           6
8       T           2
9       P           8


A
   C
      F
      O

B
  D
    J
  T
    P
```

now, if I give 2, this function should return:

```
6
8
7
9
```

and also if I give 3 it function should return:

```
4
5
```

- I don't want just leaf nodes !!!
- I think there is a sql query.

Comment: There is similar question and good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tree . 
This might be a duplicate question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just sql :

```
select  id,
        title,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) base,
        (select @pv := '3') tmp
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join table with itself. I haven't try it myself but it is like code below

```
SELECT a.id, a.title 
FROM tbl AS a 
WHERE a.id = :id

UNION

SELECT b.id, b.title
FROM tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON a.id = b.parent_id 
WHERE a.id = :id

UNION

SELECT c.id, c.title
FROM tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON a.id = b.parent_id
INNER JOIN tbl AS c ON b.id = c.parent_id 
WHERE a.id = :id

UNION

SELECT d.id, d.title
FROM tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON a.id = b.parent_id
INNER JOIN tbl AS c ON b.id = c.parent_id 
INNER JOIN tbl AS d ON c.id = d.parent_id 
WHERE a.id = :id

 ...
```

Keep adding query until number of depth you require. There is other approach for example using stored procedure.

Comment: I think it doesn't a good idea . because if I want to fetch depth 50  ? and `depth` not available !

Comment: I believe if there is no parent child relationship inner join simply return no result set. However the more depth the more resources it needs