# PHP assignment operator =&

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference assignment operator in php =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php)

What does the *=&* assignment operator mean in PHP? I could not find any reference in PHP Manual in assignment section.

I saw it in a class instantiation, so I quite don't understand what's the difference between *=&* and solely *=*.

Answer (score 8):

It means [reference assignment](http://www.php.net/references).

There are two differences between `=` and `=&`.

First, `=` does not create reference sets:

```
$a = 1;
$b = $a;
$a = 5; // $b is still 1
```

On the other hand, the `=&` operator does create reference sets:

```
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$a = 5; // $b is also 5
```

Second, `=` changes the value of all variables in the reference set, while `=&` breaks the reference set. Compare the example before with this:

```
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c = 5;
$a =& $c; // $a is 5, $b is 1
```

Comment: Don't see the use of &= in the third example. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a Reference Assignment. It makes the assigned-to variable point to the same value as the assigned-from variable.

In PHP 4, this was fairly common when assigning objects and arrays otherwise you would get a copy of the object or array. This was bad for memory management and also certain types of programming.

In PHP 5, objects and arrays are reference-counted, not copied, so reference assignment is needed much less often. Some programmers still use it 'just in case' PHP for some reason decides a copy makes sense there. But a reference assignment is still valid in other ways, such as with scalar variables, which are normally copied on assignment.

Answer (score -1):

It's a <s>[reference assignment](http://www.daaq.net/old/php/index.php?page=php+variables&parent=php+basics)</s>(deadlink) which is really two different operators.

The `=` is the assignment and the `&` accesses the value on the right by reference.

Comment: You cannot "access a value by reference" in PHP. As Artefacto's answer says, this is a single operator which creates a *reference set*, where *the variables on both sides* are bound together.