# In PHP, what's the diff : $var2=$var1 ; $var2=&$var1;

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference assignment operator in php =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php)

```
$var2 = $var1;
$var2 = &$var1;
```

Example:

```
$GLOBALS['a']=1;


function test()
{
    global $a;
    $local=2;
    $a=&$local;
}


test();

echo $a;
```

Why is $a still 1 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The operator =& works with references and not values.
The difference between `$var2=$var1` and `$var2=&$var1` is visible in this case :

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = $var1;
$var1 = 2;
echo $var1 . " " . $var2; // Prints '2 1'

$var1 = 1;
$var2 =& $var1;
$var1 = 2;
echo $var1 . " " . $var2; // Prints '2 2'
```

When you use the =& operator you don't say to $var2 "take the value of $var1 now" instead you say something like "Your value will be stored at the exact same place that the value of $var1".
So anytime you change the content of $var1 or $var2, you will see the modification in the two variables.

For more informations look on [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

EDIT :
For the global part, you'll need to use `$GLOBALS["a"] =& $local;` Cf. documentation.

Comment: "If you assign a reference to a variable declared global inside a function, the reference will be visible only inside the function. You can avoid this by using the $GLOBALS array." Check the link i gave you, there is an entire section about globals.

Answer (score 5):

When you do `$var2 = $var1`, PHP creates a copy of `$var1`, and places it in `$var2`. However, if you do `$var2 = &$var1`, no copy is made. Instead, PHP makes `$var2` point at `$var1` - what this means is that you end up with two variables that point at the **exact** same thing.

An example:

```
$var1 = "Foo";
$var2 = $var1; // NORMAL assignment - $var1's value is copied into $var2
$var3 = &$var1; // NOT normal copy!

echo $var2; // Prints "Foo".
echo $var3; // Also prints "Foo".

$var1 = "Bar"; // Change $var1.

echo $var2; // Prints "Foo" as before.
echo $var3; // Now prints "Bar"!
```

Comment: wow, cloning the variable. neat. didn't know that.

Comment: "PHP makes $var2 point at $var1 - what this means is that you end up with two variables that point at the exact same thing." you're contradicting yourself; and only the second part is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
global $a;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$a = &$GLOBALS['a'];
```

When you assign `$a` a new reference, you're changing `$a` and not `$GLOBALS['a']`.

What do you expect to be output below?

```
$GLOBALS['a']=1;

function test()
{
    $a='foobar';          // $a is a normal variable
    $a=&$GLOBALS['a'];    // same as: global $a;
    $local=2;
    $a=&$local;
}

test();

echo $a;
```