# What does =& mean?

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference assignment operator in php =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php)

I saw this example:

```
function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }
```

What does the =& mean? Is it the same as "set" or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference assignment operator in php =&](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) all linked through from the [tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)

Comment: If you need to ask this, CodeIgniter is probably not a good choice of framework for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's to assign the value [returned by the function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) as a reference.

Comment: Just a note for the asker -- it could also be written as `$this->ci = &get_instance();`

Comment: Thanks I was looking at the operator page... http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php Duh.

Comment: The sad truth in this case actually is that the `&` here is superfluous and is there because of PHP 4 (!) compatbility of Codeigniter. So better not only link the manual but to actually answer the question. By the design of the software, this does nothing. You should not write that `&` in your own code, e.g. your controller classes.