# PHP pass by reference difference between equals ampersand and equals space ampersand

Tags: php, reference

when working with references in PHP is there any difference between `=& $var` and `= &$var` ?  or it is the same thing.

I have seen this used in frameworks such as Codeigniter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php

Comment: There's no difference between them.