# What Does the & (ampersand) symbol mean in this circumstance?

Tags: php, mysql, html, send

I'm new to php and mysql. Im following a tutorial from phpacademy on youtube. There is a section that is of form data, but everyone who followed the tutorial (myself included) got undefined index errors. I fixed it with `&` (ampersand) symbol. But what does it do in the follow circumstances?? Why does putting the & symbol in front of the $ stop the error? Is it  the same as @ and is it just suppressing the error or did it actually fix it?

```
$submit = &$_POST['submit'];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526555/what-does-this-php-operator-means and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means instead of assigning the value to `$submit`, assign a reference to the value to `$submit`.

If you are familiar with C and pointers, it is like a pointer to the value that is automatically dereferenced when you access it. However, PHP doesn't allow things pointer arithmetic or getting the actual memory address (unlike C).

```
$a = 7;
$b = $a;
$c = &$a;
$c = 5;

echo $a, $b, $c; // 575
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/OzNGq9Dt).

To stop the error you mentioned, you can use a pattern such as...

```
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : 'default_value';
```

...or...

```
$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit');
```

Comment: `They are not like C pointers` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)

Comment: So that is a good way to fix the undefined index error? I am familiar with nothing... hahaha

Comment: @RyanSinclair not. Try `$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : '';`

Comment: `In PHP 5.3 ALL objects are passed by reference so neither ampersand has any legitimate need any longer. The correct edit is to remove BOTH ampersands.`

Comment: @GabrielSantos Ok, so you can't do pointer arithmetic or get the actual address, but they are kind of similar.

Comment: Yes. I posted just to not confuse the author's question

Comment: `They are not like C pointers` but `it is like a pointer to the value that is automatically dereferenced when you access it.`

Comment: I used $submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit'); and it worked. Not sure why but its working!

Comment: Thanks for the quick and extremely helpful advice everyone! you make learning all this so much simpler!