# CodeIgniter 3.1. Class Loader. Cannot understand the line $this->_ci_classes =& is_loaded();

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need some help with CodeIgniter framework 3.1. Class Loader.

I cannot understand the line **`$this->_ci_classes =& is_loaded();`**
The expression **`&is_loaded();`** is correct?

```
class CI_Loader {

protected $_ci_classes =    array();
...

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_ci_classes =& is_loaded();

    ...
}

...
public function is_loaded($class)
{
    return array_search(ucfirst($class), $this->_ci_classes, TRUE);
}
...
```

...

Answer (score 1):

### What is `protected $_ci_classes`??

just an variable which declared as protected, to use inside class.  Read [PHP: Public, Private, Protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected). It can assign to `array()` or `string` as well.

---

### What does by `=&` ??

It means assign the reference to Right hand side from Left hand side. Simply `Left = Right`. Read [What does the PHP operator =& mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526555/what-does-the-php-operator-mean)

```
$a = 1000; # $a assign to 1000
$b =& $a; # $b has same value of $a(1000)
```

---

### What `array_search(ucfirst($class), $this->_ci_classes, TRUE)` does ??

When ever you add libraries on `autoload.php`, for the our view it is an just a library. But inside CI its is an class which is defined on system folder. So when ever you load the library its allowed to use by this Load class. That's the function of `CI_Loader` Class

Read [PHP `array_search()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp)

```
/**
 * Is Loaded
 *
 * A utility method to test if a class is in the self::$_ci_classes array.
 *
 * @used-by Mainly used by Form Helper function _get_validation_object().
 *
 * @param   string      $class  Class name to check for
 * @return  string|bool Class object name if loaded or FALSE
 */
```