# PHP equals and operators

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [what do “=&” / “&=” operators in php mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean)

Sorry guys I feel like I'm asking too simple of a question but what is =& in PHP? I tried to use this group function with ACL in Cakephp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `=&` when you want to assign a variable by reference. For more information see http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php.

**Example:**

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
// $b is a reference to $a.
// If you change $a or $b, the value for both $a and $b will be changed.
$b =& $a;

$c = array(1, 2, 3);
// $d is a copy of $c.
// If you change $d, $c remains unchanged.
$d = $c;
```

Comment: So this would be similar to $$ variable variable?

Comment: @Jae Choi - No. The only time you'd want to use `$$` is if you want to dynamically refer to a variable. For instance: `$variable = 'test';` you could do `$$variable` and PHP would interpret it at `$test` (it replaces the `$variable` with it's value) but I wouldn't recommend coding that way. It'll make your code extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = 3;
$a =& $b;
$b = 5; //$a is 5 now
$a = 7; //$b is 7 now
```