# difference between "=& new SomeObject" and " = new SomeObject" in php5

Tags: php, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what do “=&” / “&=” operators in php mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

If I understand correctly `=&` is deprecated in php5 and `=& new Obj` equal `= new Obj`. I have an old package code

```
$V8fa14cdd =& new FileMaker_Field($Vc6140495);
```

So on localhost it works just fine but when I copy to remote server php fails.  If I remove `&`

```
$V8fa14cdd = new FileMaker_Field($Vc6140495);
```

script works on both servers but result is incorrect. It seems like now it uses the same copy so as result I get just

```
Array
(
[town] => town
)
```

When I add `&` result changes to

```
Array
(
[AddrCalc] => AddrCalc
[AllowAccess] => AllowAccess
[ComNameCalc] => ComNameCalc
[DBID] => DBID
[DBexist] => DBexist
[FoundCount] => FoundCount
[Full_Name] => Full_Name
[addr1] => addr1
[business_name] => business_name
[country] => country
[county] => county
[email] => email
[fax] => fax
[firstname] => firstname
[flag] => flag
[fmconfirm] => fmconfirm
[hash] => hash
[id] => id
[lastname] => lastname
[mobile] => mobile
[modified] => modified
[modifiedCalc] => modifiedCalc
[password] => password
[postcode] => postcode
[ref1] => ref1
[ref2] => ref2
[ref3] => ref3
[ref4] => ref4
[telephone] => telephone
[town] => town
)
```

so is there any idea why thats happen?

Comment: [off topic: what's with the crazy variable names? `$V8fa14cdd` ?]

Comment: its need to ask falemaker developers :). This code from their API