# Real example of "=&" usage

Tags: php, operators

I know `$a =& $b` assigns `$a` as a reference to `$b` and I already read some answers about it, but no one provides a real useful example usage includes: [What do the "=&" and "&=" operators in PHP mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean)

Could any one provide a minimal example to show how `=&` could be useful in PHP? Why might somebody want to have two names for a single variable?

Comment: This question does not have an answer there!

Comment: i thought Zenexer answer was very thorough

Comment: And what specifically would qualify a "real" example? The manual already contains some in the comments: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php - I don't see how this broad inquiry solves a coding need. Don't forcibly try to use fringe features.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example. You are assigning the reference of `$var1` to `$var2` , so when you change `$var2` , `$var1` value changes.

```
<?php
$var1 = 10;
$var2 = 20;
$var2 = &$var1;
$var2 = 200;
echo $var1; // 200;
```

Comment: I am looking for a real useful example.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose some user defined function manipulate a string:

```
function test($string){
    $string.='bar';
    return $string;
}
```

In this case, you would have to attribute the return of the function back to the variable:

```
$foo='foo';
$foo=test($foo);
```

Passing the variable by reference you could eliminate some code:

```
function test(&$string){
    $string.='bar';
}

$foo='foo';
test($foo);
```

Just like, for example, the native `settype` works. Look the ampersand at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php).

Answer (score 0):

Really useful example is modifying tree-alike structures:

Assuming you have a tree path like 'a.b.c' and an array:

```
array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => array(
            'c' => array(),
        ),
    ),
)
```

and you need to insert a new value in the deepest element. That you could end up with something like (not tested, just for demonstration purposes):

```
$parts = explode('.', $path);
$node = &$tree;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if (isset($node[$part])) {
        $node = &$node[$part];
    } else {
        $node = null;
        break;
    }
}

if (!is_null($node)) {
    $node[] = 'new value';
}
```

Comment: `$tree` was initialized?

Comment: @Rafael Barros: of course not - the data appears from somewhere magically