# PHP different usage of reference sign &

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the different usage of & in the following two examples:

```
$x = &$b; // which I know what it does
```

But what about this one:

```
$x &= get_instance();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean

Comment: thanks. Read those questions.

Answer (score 1):

&= is the "bitwise and"-assignment operator. In PHP

```
$a &= $b;
```

is the same as

```
$a = $a & $b;
```

"bitwise and" means that two corresponding bits of two arguments are evaluated using the and-operator. If the arguments are not integers, they are converted to integer values first. For details you can refer to the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).