# What is the point of assigning by reference?

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

A simple question just to feed my curiosity. What is the point of assigning variables by reference in PHP? I get how referencing works and how it can be useful (like passing by reference for example). But is there any practical scenario where I would really need or like to **assign** by reference? (like in `$a =& $b;` for example). Why would I want to create two variable names which both essentially point to the same value and doing anything to either of them also takes effect on the other? Why can't I just do all operations on the original variable and only assign (but not by reference) another one if I need to fork the values?

Comment: i.e. to edit deep arrays or foreach loops

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165936/1583432) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's some examples:

Making aliases for very long variables

```
$config = array(
   'developers' =>  => array(
         'emails' => array()
      ),
);
$dev_emails = &$config['developers']['emails'];
$dev_emails[] = 'email1@tld.com';
$dev_emails[] = 'email2@tld.com';
$dev_emails[] = 'email3@tld.com';
```

Naming a single value with a different name

```
$result_count = mysql_num_rows();
$table_rows = &$number_of_results;
```

Assigning array items early

```
$post = $_POST;
$time = time();
$article = array(
    'article_contents' => &$post['contents'],
    'article_title' => &$post['title'],
    'article_tags' => &$post['tags'],
    'insert_time' => &$time
);

if (array_filter($article) < 3) {
   throw new Exception("Required fields are blank");
}

$post['contents'] = striptags($post['contents']);

# imaginary model
# article::insert($article);
```

^ This one seems to be impractical even to me, but I know this was useful to me for a number of times

Saving memory? ( just a theory )

There's still a lot more application that will only appear when you're coding, you'll notice where it's useful when you're already coding

Comment: Good example of using reference as a kind of "alias" for a more complex variable!

Answer (score 2):

At one time, it was possible that this saved memory by avoiding copying long strings. But modern versions of PHP use copy-on-write, so this isn't as much of an issue.

That is, copy on write means if you assign `$a = $b`, it doesn't actually use more memory. `$a` internally points to the same content in memory that `$b` points to. But they're not supposed to be linked as though by reference. So if you modify `$b`, then at that moment PHP makes `$a` a physical copy of the original value of `$b`. If you modify `$a`, then it gets its own memory space for its new value.

References are still useful for side effects.

For example, when using foreach:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach ($a as $value) {
  $value *= 2; // does not change contents of $a
}

foreach ($a as &$value) {
  $value *= 2; // changes contents of $a
}
```

Or when passing function arguments, and you want the function to modify the value of the argument.

Comment: Passing by reference is something I use myself quite frequently. I was specifically curious about assigning by reference outside of places with calling functions or loops. But the note about legacy memory considerations was quite interesting, thank you.